# Getting ioctl(setctty): operation not permitted: unknown error in K8S-Docker setup

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, containers

Getting the permission error when trying to start a container in Ubuntu-AWS virtual machine. I am using kubectl apply -f test.yaml to deploy. Nginx is working normally in the same VM. I tried changing permissions, privilege modes and others with no luck.

Kindly help me resolve the error. Thanks in advance.

```
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$ cat testc.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: testc
  labels:
    app: TESTC
    tier: testvc
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: TESTC
      tier: testc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: TESTC
        tier: testc

    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name:  modulepath
        hostPath:
          path: /lib/modules
      - name: local
        hostPath:
          path: /local/configvol
      - name: dev
        hostPath:
          path: /dev
      - name: hugepage
        emptyDir:
          medium: HugePages
      - name: day0-config
        configMap:
          name: day0-config
          optional: true
          items:
          - key: day0-config
            path: day0-config
      - name: vpn-config
        configMap:
          name: vpn-config
          optional: true
          items:
          - key: vpn-config
            path: vpn-config
      - name: interface-config
        configMap:
          name: interface-config
          optional: true
          items:
          - key: interface-config
            path: interface-config
      - name: day0-idtoken
        secret:
          secretName: day0-idtoken
          optional: true
          items:
          - key: idtoken
            path: idtoken

      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regtestc

      containers:
      - name: testc
        image: dockerhub.privaterepo.com/testc-dev-docker/testc:99.22.24.5
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        stdin: true
        tty: true
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
                add: ["SYS_RESOURCE", "SYS_ADMIN", "NET_ADMIN"]
          privileged: true
        env:
        - name: TEST_DOCKER
          value: "1"
        - name: RUN_TEST_WITH_GDB
          value: "0"
        - name: TESTC_MEMORY
          value: "2048M"
        - name: TESTC_CPUS
          value: "1"
        - name: DISABLE_DPDK
          value: "0"
        - name: TEST_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: TEST_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: TEST_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: CORE_SIZE_LIMIT
          value: "200MB"
        - name: COREDUMP_PATH
          value: "/mnt/coredump_repo/"
        - name: TESTC_DEALER_ENDPOINT
          value: "localhost:5555"
        - name: TESTC_STANDALONE_MODE
          value: "1"
        - name: TESTC_ROOT_PRIVILEGE
          value: "1"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: modulepath
            mountPath: /lib/modules
          - name: local
            mountPath: /config
          - name: dev
            mountPath: /dev
          - mountPath: /hugepages
            name: hugepage
          - name: day0-config
            mountPath: /testc-day0-config
          - name: vpn-config
            mountPath: /mnt/vpn-config
            subPath: vpn-config
          - name: day0-idtoken
            mountPath: /testc-day0-idtoken
            readOnly: true
          - name: interface-config
            mountPath: /mnt/interface-config

        resources:
          limits:
            hugepages-2Mi: 64Mi
            memory: 2Gi
          requests:
            hugepages-2Mi: 64Mi
            memory: 2Gi
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$ kubectl get pod
NAME         READY   STATUS              RESTARTS     AGE
testc-k28fj   0/1     RunContainerError   0 (4s ago)   4s
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$ kubectl describe pod
Name:             testc-k28fj
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:       Fri, 22 Sep 2023 06:35:30 +0000
Labels:           app=TESTC
                  controller-revision-hash=6556668fd7
                  pod-template-generation=1
                  tier=testc
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.49.2
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.49.2
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/testc
Containers:
  testc:
    Container ID:   docker://110d8b8566439997dabc20ea550481e045592e2ecded34952fb5a1d601ddf4e2
    Image:          dockerhub.privaterepo.com/testc-dev-docker/testc:99.22.24.5
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:9f0691a7a21614290abd79a5fc477199cd1a705be1aefff06fc7a903ed1a686b
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       RunContainerError
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerCannotRun
      Message:      failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: ioctl(setctty): operation not permitted: unknown
      Exit Code:    128
      Started:      Fri, 22 Sep 2023 06:35:30 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 22 Sep 2023 06:35:30 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
    Limits:
      hugepages-2Mi:  64Mi
      memory:         2Gi
    Requests:
      hugepages-2Mi:  64Mi
      memory:         2Gi
    Environment:
      TEST_DOCKER:            1
      RUN_TEST_WITH_GDB:      0
      TESTC_MEMORY:           2048M
      TESTC_CPUS:             1
      DISABLE_DPDK:          0
      TEST_POD_NAME:          testc-k28fj (v1:metadata.name)
      TEST_POD_NAMESPACE:     default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      TEST_POD_IP:             (v1:status.podIP)
      CORE_SIZE_LIMIT:       200MB
      COREDUMP_PATH:         /mnt/coredump_repo/
      TESTC_DEALER_ENDPOINT:  localhost:5555
      TESTC_STANDALONE_MODE:  1
      TESTC_ROOT_PRIVILEGE:   1
    Mounts:
      /testc-day0-config from day0-config (rw)
      /testc-day0-idtoken from day0-idtoken (ro)
      /config from local (rw)
      /dev from dev (rw)
      /hugepages from hugepage (rw)
      /lib/modules from modulepath (rw)
      /mnt/interface-config from interface-config (rw)
      /mnt/vpn-config from vpn-config (rw,path="vpn-config")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-7pb8t (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  modulepath:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /lib/modules
    HostPathType:
  local:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /local/configvol
    HostPathType:
  dev:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /dev
    HostPathType:
  hugepage:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     HugePages
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  day0-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      day0-config
    Optional:  true
  vpn-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      vpn-config
    Optional:  true
  interface-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      interface-config
    Optional:  true
  day0-idtoken:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  day0-idtoken
    Optional:    true
  kube-api-access-7pb8t:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  14s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/testc-k28fj to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     1s (x3 over 14s)  kubelet            Container image "dockerhub.privaterepo.com/testc-dev-docker/testc:99.22.24.5" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    1s (x3 over 14s)  kubelet            Created container testc
  Warning  Failed     1s (x3 over 14s)  kubelet            Error: failed to start container "testc": Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: ioctl(setctty): operation not permitted: unknown
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$ kubectl get pod
NAME         READY   STATUS              RESTARTS     AGE
testc-k28fj   0/1     RunContainerError   0 (4s ago)   4s
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$ kubectl describe pod
Name:             testc-k28fj
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             minikube/192.168.49.2
Start Time:       Fri, 22 Sep 2023 06:35:30 +0000
Labels:           app=TESTC
                  controller-revision-hash=6556668fd7
                  pod-template-generation=1
                  tier=testc
Annotations:      <none>
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.49.2
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.49.2
Controlled By:  DaemonSet/testc
Containers:
  testc:
    Container ID:   docker://110d8b8566439997dabc20ea550481e045592e2ecded34952fb5a1d601ddf4e2
    Image:          dockerhub.privaterepo.com/testc-dev-docker/testc:99.22.24.5
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:9f0691a7a21614290abd79a5fc477199cd1a705be1aefff06fc7a903ed1a686b
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       RunContainerError
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerCannotRun
      Message:      failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: ioctl(setctty): operation not permitted: unknown
      Exit Code:    128
      Started:      Fri, 22 Sep 2023 06:35:30 +0000
      Finished:     Fri, 22 Sep 2023 06:35:30 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
    Limits:
      hugepages-2Mi:  64Mi
      memory:         2Gi
    Requests:
      hugepages-2Mi:  64Mi
      memory:         2Gi
    Environment:
      TEST_DOCKER:            1
      RUN_TEST_WITH_GDB:      0
      TESTC_MEMORY:           2048M
      TESTC_CPUS:             1
      DISABLE_DPDK:          0
      TEST_POD_NAME:          testc-k28fj (v1:metadata.name)
      TEST_POD_NAMESPACE:     default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      TEST_POD_IP:             (v1:status.podIP)
      CORE_SIZE_LIMIT:       200MB
      COREDUMP_PATH:         /mnt/coredump_repo/
      TESTC_DEALER_ENDPOINT:  localhost:5555
      TESTC_STANDALONE_MODE:  1
      TESTC_ROOT_PRIVILEGE:   1
    Mounts:
      /testc-day0-config from day0-config (rw)
      /testc-day0-idtoken from day0-idtoken (ro)
      /config from local (rw)
      /dev from dev (rw)
      /hugepages from hugepage (rw)
      /lib/modules from modulepath (rw)
      /mnt/interface-config from interface-config (rw)
      /mnt/vpn-config from vpn-config (rw,path="vpn-config")
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-7pb8t (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  modulepath:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /lib/modules
    HostPathType:
  local:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /local/configvol
    HostPathType:
  dev:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /dev
    HostPathType:
  hugepage:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     HugePages
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  day0-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      day0-config
    Optional:  true
  vpn-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      vpn-config
    Optional:  true
  interface-config:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      interface-config
    Optional:  true
  day0-idtoken:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  day0-idtoken
    Optional:    true
  kube-api-access-7pb8t:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/disk-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/memory-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/network-unavailable:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/pid-pressure:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/unschedulable:NoSchedule op=Exists
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  14s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/testc-k28fj to minikube
  Normal   Pulled     1s (x3 over 14s)  kubelet            Container image "dockerhub.privaterepo.com/testc-dev-docker/testc:99.22.24.5" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    1s (x3 over 14s)  kubelet            Created container testc
  Warning  Failed     1s (x3 over 14s)  kubelet            Error: failed to start container "testc": Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: ioctl(setctty): operation not permitted: unknown
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$
ubuntu@rd-testc-virtual:~/TESTc$
```